# Nested Slider addition

Tags: slider, nested

I am trying to mimic the Nested Slider from the link below.
The only way I was able to do this was copy the Source Code and trim the banners etc.

Couple Questions:

1. Is there a way to locate the source code for this specific example with CSS and JS?
2. I am trying to add another nested section....right now the example has 3...and have been unsuccessful...
   I added anohter sliderh4_container here

$Jssor$.$Each(["sliderh1_container", "sliderh2_container", "sliderh3_container", "sliderh4_container"], function (containerId) {

But cant seem to get this to work...
And then added slider container in HTML....

http://www.jssor.com/index.html

ANY IDEAS....help?  thanks in advance...

Comment: It appears that all four are there but I can only see the other one when I select an existing one...if that makes sense...I need to change the code so that all 4 are visible from the get go...

Comment: OK I was correct the code I added above did add a 4th slider container...BUT I cant figure out how to show all 4 containers at the bottom of the Nested Container example...PLEASE help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust thumbnail size.

For example, to resize thumbnail from 200 x 100 to 150 x 100, please replace,

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move;">
    <div u="prototype" class=p style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 200px; HEIGHT: 100px; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0;">
        <thumbnailtemplate style="WIDTH: 200px; HEIGHT: 100px; border: none; position: absolute; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0; "></thumbnailtemplate>
    </div>
</div>
```

with

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move;">
    <div u="prototype" class=p style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 150px; HEIGHT: 100px; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0;">
        <thumbnailtemplate style="WIDTH: 150px; HEIGHT: 100px; border: none; position: absolute; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0; "></thumbnailtemplate>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, you need to change $DisplayPieces from 3 to 4,

```
$ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
    $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

    $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
    $AutoCenter: 3,                                 //[Optional] Auto center thumbnail items in the thumbnail navigator container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 3
    $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange thumbnails, default value is 1
    $SpacingX: 0,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
    $SpacingY: 0,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
    $Cols: 4,                              //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
    $Align: 0,                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
    $Orientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to arrange thumbnails, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
    $DisableDrag: false                            //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
}
```

Comment: Dang I was all around that....cant believe I missed that...Thanks for the extra set of eyes....very appreciated.